# How to write Vault LDAP Auth Configuration from a json config file?

Tags: bash, shell, ldap, hashicorp-vault

In my hashicorp vault container. I want to use the the ldap auth method to allows authentication
https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/ldap.html

I'm writing a shell script that should write vault ldap configuration from a json file. My vault ldap configuration with the connection parameters is stored in the same directory and is named as parameters.json. What is the correct syntax to load LDAP connection parameters from an external file?

```
vault auth enable ldap
vault write auth/ldap/config config=@parameters.json
```

The above command does not overwrite the values from this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made it work by replacing it with a text value with key value pair (key1=value 1 .... key n..value n)

```
vault write auth/ldap/config binddn=@binddn bindpass=@bindpass url =@url
```

Apparently, the ldap connection properties need to be specified one after the another and it's not possible to import a json file to parse

Answer (score 0):

If `curl` is available, you can `POST` the data with a JSON file as the source like this:

```bash
curl -k --header "X-Vault-Token: $VAULT_TOKEN" --request POST --data @parameters.json https://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/auth/ldap/config
```

Note, that in the example TLS verification is disabled using the `-k` argument. This should not be done in production deployments were TLS can be verified correctly.